# ModelChoiceField django

Tags: python, django

I have created a Django form to get the data from user and search that given data in database models.
But i am not able to use the dropdown functionality correctly. I have used ModelChoiceField but I am getting it empty.
I have three fields(forms.py) which i am searching in the database.

models.py

```
class Release(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    changes = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return unicode(self.number)

class Metamodule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    version = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    release = models.ForeignKey(Release,related_name="num")
    createdate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    createdby = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return unicode(self.name)


class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    version = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    metamodule = models.ForeignKey(Metamodule,related_name="metaname")
    createdate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    changes = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return unicode(self.name)
```

forms.py

```
class ModuleForm(forms.Form):
     release_num = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Release.objects.all().values('number'),empty_label='Pick a Release')
     metamodule_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
     module_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from search.forms import ModuleForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from search.models import Module,Metamodule,Release

def searchview(request):
     if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ModuleForm(request.GET)  
    if form.is_valid():
      release_num = form.cleaned_data['release_num']
      metamodule_name = form.cleaned_data['metamodule_name']
      module_name = form.cleaned_data['module_name']
      results = Module.objects.filter(metamodule__release__number=release_num).filter(metamodule__name=metamodule_name).filter(name=module_name)
      return render(request,'search/search_result.html',{'form': form, 'results': results})
     else:
     form = ModuleForm()    
     return render(request, 'search/search_form.html',{'form': form})
```

search_form.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
     {% if error %}
        <p style="color: red;">Please submit a search term.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="/search/" method="get">
        <select name="release_num">
            {% for release_num in release_num %}
            <option value="{{ release_num.number }}">{{ release_num.number }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
    </select>   
    <p><label for="metamodule_name">Metamodule:</label>
    <input type="text" name="metamodule_name">
    <p><label for="module_name">Module:</label>
    <input type="text" name="module_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `queryset=Release.objects.all().values('number')` to `queryset=Release.objects.all()`

Comment: @Karthikr: But i want to list only the number filed for that release_num dropdown list?

Comment: That is what would happen. Since your unicode points to the `number` field anyways.

Comment: @karthikr: I have changed it, but the output is same. It is not showing the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in the search_form.html:

```
 <form action="/search/" method="get">
    {{ form.release_num }}
   {{ form.metamodule_name  }}
   {{ form.module_name }}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of dynamic filtering of dropdown lists?

Comment: for mor manupilation you can check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template  to customize the form template

Comment: you want to apply filter to your queryset in ModelChoiceField ?

Comment: Ya. Two models are related with a foreign key. I mean if i select an item in first dropdown box, items in second dropdown should be filtered. The list should be only items related to 1st selected option. The filtering should be dynamic with the selection.